# Is there a value-neutral word for Brandolini's law?

Tags: single-word-requests, concept

As you may know, [Brandolini’s law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandolini%27s_law) states:

> The amount of energy needed to refute bullshit is an order of magnitude bigger than that needed to produce it.

I am looking for a term that shows the asymmetry between just making a hypothesis or claim or allegation (which is easy to do, hence the derogatory remarks like "empty theorizing") and providing a proof or evidence for the claim (which takes a lot of energy).  If you use it strictly, Brandolini’s law is only applicable to bullshit or wrong claims but not for reasonable claims (that is, claims that may be right).

Is there a recognized term for this that covers both types of claims, meaning that they could be bullshit ***or*** factual but that the proof is always hard?

ChatGPT suggested *asymmetry of proof* and *verification asymmetry*, but neither of these is a popular or recognized term even though both make some sense. The closest thing I could find conceptually is [*burden of proof*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(philosophy)).

I guess the *burden of proof* idea also comes from this asymmetry. Is this a recognized issue in general, meaning that hypotheses are cheap but proofs take work? If so, what words or concepts do philosophers, thinkers, or scientists use to address this issue?

Comment: 'Is this a recognized issue in general ... ie hypotheses are cheap, proofs take work?' is a question for a science or maths forum, T. A word / expression naming the phenomenon if true is perhaps better sought on a science website also, though this _might_ be general enough a question for ELU.

Comment: The usual observation is that ***creating*** something takes far longer than ***destroying*** it. But in this case it seems to be the opposite - some wally comes up with a stupid idea in a few seconds, but apparently it takes *hours* to rip the idea apart. Is that a thing?  It doesn't make much sense to me. Usually, we assume that the real truth of a situation should be self-evident once it's actually spelled out. For example, even a ten-year-old should be able to demolish primitive "flat earther" thinking in a few sentences, *if he knows what arguments to put forward*.

Comment: As this is a single word request, you need to give an example sentence with the required word as a blank

Comment: The twin prime conjecture, the Riemann hypothesis and so on can be stated if not simply then succinctly and clearly (to a mathematician). These are almost universally believed to be true laws, but remain unproved. You seem to be looking for hypotheses which are almost universally believed to be falde but which have not been proved so to be.

Comment: "shows the asymmetry in the energy **needed** to make a claim or hypothesis and proving it". I had to read it like four times to get it.

Comment: Not quite the same thing, but a [one-way hash argument](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/One-way_hash_argument) is a (bad) argument for which Brandolini's law is true, i.e. it's simple to make but hard to refute. The claim isn't actually true of everything, since some arguments are so stupid or wrong they can be immediately refuted.

Answer (score -1):

This is not 'value-neutral', but a simple way to say it is

> **mud sticks**
>
> said to mean that people are likely to believe something bad that is said about someone, even if it is not true

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mud-sticks).

The normal usage applies to people, but it illustrates how difficult it can be to refute random allegations. All the perpetrator needs to do is to appeal to the emotions of the reader, with no proof required. Having stirred those emotions, even a complete proof of their falsity may not be enough to counteract it.

Comment: Almost like The Big LIe.

Comment: Is this about throwing shite at a wall and seeing if it sticks? Somehow just "mud sticks" doesn't do it for me...

Comment: @Lambie I'd guess that it has more to do with "mud-slinging".

Comment: @user888379 But mud slinging on its own refers to tarnishing a reputation, doesn't it?

Comment: @Lambie It does - and my thinking is that "mud sticks" is a succinct way of saying "tarnishing a reputation is easier than burnishing one"

Comment: @user888379 I guess it doesn't matter too much since I find the answer completely off. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and yeah, the term seems to be related to what I have asked for, but it is even more restricted than Brandolini's law for me for it only relates to gossip about people. What I am looking for is a term that would cover the general idea that the effort involved in putting out a random theory (anyone can conjure up a random theory) vs. validating your random theory (which is way hard) is very asymmetrical .

Comment: @Lambie "mud sticks" is a BrE idiom if you'd care to read the link.